# ant command for block replacement

Tags: maven, ant

I have an HTML file containing block of code  which is bounded by predefined text like

@begin@

MYcode line 1

Mycode line 2

some other code

@end@

I would like to run mvn ant command to do processing on this file such that 
any text between @begin@  to @end@ should be replaced by multi block statment i had.
like

@begin@

This is my final code

@end@

Thanks

keshav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<replaceregexp match="@begin@;(.*?)@end@;"
                                    replace="Any Text you want"
                                    flags="gs">
<fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="*.*"/>
```

Above code will do replacement of regular expression for the tokens.